# Objeto só fica disponível quando dou dd()?

Tags: laravel-5

Estou setando um atributo de um array, ele esta acessível apenas quando dou `dd()` faço assim:

```
dd($categoria->categoria->NmCategoria)
```

Ele funciona caso eu faça da forma natural assim:

```
 @foreach($subcategorias as $categoria)
    <tr>
      <td>{{ $categoria->CdSubCategoria }}</td>
      <td>{{ $categoria->categoria->NmCategoria }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

No meu controller faço assim:

```
$subcategorias =  SubCategoria::with('categoria')->get();

if(Request::wantsJson())
{
    return $subcategorias;
}
else
{
    return view('SubCategoria.listSubCategoria', compact('subcategorias'));
}
```

`var_dump` de `$subcategorias`:

> array(3) { [0]=> array(11) { ["CdSubCategoria"]=> int(1) ["CdCategoria"]=> >int(3) ["NmSubCategoria"]=> string(17) "Torta sem gluten." >["DscSubCategoria"]=> string(40) "Categoria destinada aos pães sem glutem" >["FlgPontua"]=> int(0) ["QtdPontos"]=> int(1) >["MaxPontosPorSubCategoria"]=> int(0) ["created_at"]=> string(19) >"2016-09-10 14:25:22" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2016-09-14 22:16:03" >["deleted_at"]=> NULL ["categoria"]=> array(6) { ["CdCategoria"]=> int(3) >["NmCategoria"]=> string(5) "Pão1" ["DscCategoria"]=> string(31) "Categoria >destinadas aos pães." ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2016-09-09 00:12:36" >["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2016-09-09 00:12:36" ["deleted_at"]=> NULL } } >[1]=> array(11) { ["CdSubCategoria"]=> int(3) ["CdCategoria"]=> int(5) >["NmSubCategoria"]=> string(29) "Bolo sem gluten e sem lactose" >["DscSubCategoria"]=> string(33) "Produtos sem gluten e sem lactose" >["FlgPontua"]=> int(1) ["QtdPontos"]=> int(10) >["MaxPontosPorSubCategoria"]=> int(0) ["created_at"]=> string(19) >"2016-09-10 20:34:29" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2016-09-10 20:34:29" >["deleted_at"]=> NULL ["categoria"]=> array(6) { ["CdCategoria"]=> int(5) >["NmCategoria"]=> string(4) "Bolo" ["DscCategoria"]=> string(29) "Categoria >destinada aos bolos" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2016-09-10 20:32:45" >["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2016-09-10 20:32:45" ["deleted_at"]=> NULL } } >[2]=> array(11) { ["CdSubCategoria"]=> int(4) ["CdCategoria"]=> int(7) >["NmSubCategoria"]=> string(7) "Farinha" ["DscSubCategoria"]=> string(23) >"Farinha para fazer bolo" ["FlgPontua"]=> int(0) ["QtdPontos"]=> int(0) >["MaxPontosPorSubCategoria"]=> int(0) ["created_at"]=> string(19) >"2016-09-21 23:00:26" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2016-09-21 23:00:26" >["deleted_at"]=> NULL ["categoria"]=> NULL } }

ele não funciona e da o seguinte erro:

> Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\Users\Computador\Desktop\PROJETOS\SGLE-Padaria\resources\views\SubCategoria\listSubCategoria.blade.php)

Porque isto acontesce ?

Comment: `$subcategorias =  SubCategoria::with('categoria')->get();` depois dessa linha que está no controller da um `var_dump($subcategorias);` e cole na pergunta!

Comment: atualizado a pergunt

Comment: desculpa faz um `var_dump($subcategorias->toArray());`!!! assim é o objeto de coleção fica ruim ver o resultados.

Comment: prontinho ja att

Comment: Tem categorias que estão vindo `NULL`, fiz uma resposta!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No final do resultado do `var_dump()` tem um categoria que está vindo `NULL`

```
["categoria"]=> NULL
```

então, pelo que pude perceber pode haver `SubCategorias` sem `Categorias`?

Se sim no seu código do `foreach`

```
@foreach($subcategorias as $categoria)
 <tr>
   <td>{{ $categoria->CdSubCategoria }}</td>
   <td>{{ is_null($categoria->categoria) === false ? $categoria->categoria->NmCategoria : "sem categoria" }}</td>
 </tr>
@endforeach
```